# Concatenate a CSS name in Knockout

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I'd like to know how to apply a css class name concatenated using $data for items in my Knockout ViewModel.

### Goal

When a user clicks the "Praise" button (an item in my ViewModel array), I would like to apply the css class "feedbackItemIconPraise" to the LI. if the user clicks "Criticism", I would like to apply the class "feedbackItemIconPraise".

I assumed that concatenating a css class in the data-bind attribute using $data was the way to go but might be wrong.

### Code

Relevant part of my ViewModel:

```
var FeedbackViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.feedbackItemTypes = ['Praise', 'Criticism', 'Problem', 'Question'];
    self.selectedFeedbackType = ko.observable('Praise');
    self.updateSelected = function (param) {
        self.selectedFeedbackType(param);
    };
};

var feedbackViewModel = new FeedbackViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(feedbackViewModel, document.getElementById("feedbackModal"));
```

Relevant parts of my View display:

```
<div id="feedbackListContainer">
    <ul class="thumbnails" id="feedbackList" data-bind="foreach: feedbackItemTypes">
       <li class ="feedbackItem" data-bind="click: $parent.updateSelected, text:$data, attr:{id:'feedbackItem'+$data, title:$data}, css: {'feedbackItem-Highlighted':$data==$parent.selectedFeedbackType(), 'feedbackItemIcon'+$data: true}">
        </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

### The Problem

What I think I'm getting wrong is applying the CSS class "'feedbackItemIcon' + $data". I think I'm misunderstanding how css classes are applied and if this is possible in Knockout or at odds with how Knockout works. When I attempt to do it this way, all my text disappears, and so I assume that I'm screwing up the syntax entirely.

Would appreciate some insight.

Comment: It seems that your problem has already been solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677917/knockout-js-use-both-static-class-name-as-well-as-data-bound-class-name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're very close to a correct solution.

```
'feedbackItemIcon'+$data: true
```

You're right. **This won't work** because Knockout won't update the left side of this expression.

Instead, I would simply list all enum values and write something like this:

```
css: {'feedbackItem-Highlighted':$data==$parent.selectedFeedbackType(), 'feedbackItemIconPraise': $data==$parent.selectedFeedbackType() && $data='Praise', 'feedbackItemIconCriticism': $data==$parent.selectedFeedbackType() && $data='Criticism', 'feedbackItemIconProblem': $data==$parent.selectedFeedbackType() && $data='Problem', 'feedbackItemIconQuestion': $data==$parent.selectedFeedbackType() && $data='Question' }
```

I know that it looks a little ugly and seems a little repetitive, but AFAIK, there's no way to bind a template item to a CSS class name whose value will change at runtime.

FYI: You're probably already aware of this, but for future visitors, here is the [link to the Knockout documentation on CSS binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html).

Comment: Thanks, Jim! You're right; I was trying to avoid that because it felt like a code smell, but knowing that the way I was attempting to work it isn't possible as far as you know is very helpful indeed. Since I only have four items, it's not as big an issue, but that's definitely good to know. I'll approach the problem from this way.

Comment: Confusingly, this concat method works when there's only one key:value in the css binding object. The moment more are added it breaks

Answer (score 2):

Using the `class` custom binding [here](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class), you can do this in a different way:

```
<li class ="feedbackItem" data-bind="
    click: $parent.updateSelected,
    text: $data,
    attr: {id:'feedbackItem'+$data, title:$data},
    css: {'feedbackItem-Highlighted':$data==$parent.selectedFeedbackType()},
    class: 'feedbackItemIcon'+$data">
</li>
```

This functionality will also be part of the `css` binding in the upcoming 2.2 version of Knockout. So then you wouldn't have to include the `class` custom binding. But you wouldn't be able to include two `css` bindings. One workaround would be to just make `class` an alias of `css`: `ko.bindingHandlers['class'] = ko.bindingHandlers.css`. Another would be to use my [key.subkey](https://github.com/mbest/knockout-key.subkey) plugin, which would allow this binding:

```
<li class ="feedbackItem" data-bind="
    click: $parent.updateSelected,
    text: $data,
    attr: {id:'feedbackItem'+$data, title:$data},
    css.feedbackItem-Highlighted: $data==$parent.selectedFeedbackType(),
    css: 'feedbackItemIcon'+$data">
</li>
```

Comment: If he had 20+ CSS classes, either plug-in would probably be a good solution; but in this example, I think he'd be better off without the additional moving part. // It's encouraging to know that this will be included out of the box in Knockout 2.2.

Comment: Custom bindings and plugins are integral parts of developing with Knockout. In this case, it might actually be better for him to write a completely custom binding.

Comment: I also think that the solution that Ryan suggested is a good one: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/knockoutjs/y4CpGocZn0c/slAiWysG-f4J

Answer (score 2):

This answer is obviously late to the game, but I'd like to suggest another solution:

```
<li data-bind="attr: { 'class': ' feedbackItem ' 
                                + ($data==$parent.selectedFeedbackType() 
                                   ? ' feedbackItem-Highlighted ' : '')
                                + ' feedbackItemIcon'+$data
                     }">    </li>
```

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes. CSS handling in KO is difficult. This makes it easier.