# combine dynamic and static classes through css binding, knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In knockout.js we can use css binding for static classes

```
<div data-bind="css: {'translucent ': number() < 10}">static dynamic css classes</div>
```

and dynamic

```
<div data-bind="css: color">static dynamic css classes</div>
```

I've tried http://jsfiddle.net/tT9PK/1/ to combine it in something like

```
css: {color, translucent: number() < 10}
```

to get dynamic class `color` and static `translucent` at the same time, but I get an error. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can add dynamic class by `css` property and then add static class by `attr` property

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'class': color }, css: { 'translucent': number() < 10 }">
  static dynamic css classes
</div>
```

Be sure to add any predefined classes to this binding 
`attr: { 'class': color }`

Comment: Be sure to add any predefined classes to this binding (classes added using the actual class attr).

Comment: I think `josh_bailey4`'s comment should be integrated in the answer since it's a pretty important thing to be careful of, especially when editing existing mark-up that already has a `class` attribute on the target element. Anyway, upvoted.

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to work with dynamic class names.  If the "color" observable changes here, it will erase any classes added via the "css" binding.  See example: http://jsfiddle.net/rocketmonkeys/tzj1zj31/

Comment: Realized too late that this solution doesn't handle observable change. Can't undo my upvote. [Roy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34416301/4625305) worked for me,

Answer (score 14):

I solved this problem a while back by just cloning the `css` binding as `css2`.

```
 ko.bindingHandlers['css2'] = ko.bindingHandlers.css;
```

Normally you can't use the same binding handler twice in a data-bind attribute, so this allowed me to do the following:

```
<div data-bind="css: color, css2: { 'translucent': number() < 10 }">static dynamic css classes</div>
```

I can't quite decide whether I still prefer this, or @Aleksey's answer, but this may be the only choice if you have multiple dynamic classes to add.

Comment: I tend to favor @Aleksey's answer on this, but this approach is an interesting way of handling it.

Comment: This is valid solution, the only one that works well.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet is probably not to combine them. Instead use a computed property of your view model to combine them into a single property that you can bind dynamically. That way you can also avoid putting logic in your view with the number() < 10 binding, which is cleaner anyway.

Like this, for example:

```
viewModel.colorAndTrans = ko.computed(function () {
    var cssString = viewModel.color();
    if (viewModel.number() < 10) {
        cssString += " translucent"
    }
    return cssString;
});
```

See this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tT9PK/4/

Comment: It's simply lucky that this answer was usable to the OP. Most of the times doing this will only result in a lot of computeds (think lists) and coupled code (harder to test). `Aleksey`'s answer below, with `josh_bailey4`'s comment is a much more elegant solution and imho that should be the accepted answer, not this one. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Mtz: I disagree and there is no "luck" involved. I think it is much cleaner to not pollute the view with logic like `number() < 10`. That's kind of the point of having a view model.

Comment: Can colorAndTrans take a parameter , eg if there is loop then can we send a paramter the function as the value of the items in the loop
?

Comment: Yep, small point - use `pureComputed` instead of `computed` for some useful performance optimisations.

Answer (score 4):

Correct...and to launch you even further, check out this modification.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fv27b/2/

Here, you'll see that not only are we combining the options, but we're creating our own binding entirely...which results in a much more portable extension of not just this view model, but any view model you may have in your project...so you'll only need to write this one once!

```
ko.bindingHandlers.colorAndTrans = {
    update: function(element, valAccessor) {
        var valdata = valAccessor();
        var cssString = valdata.color();
        if (valdata.transValue() < 10) cssString += " translucent";
        element.className = cssString;
    }
}
```

To invoke this, you just use it as a new data-bind property and can include as many (or as few) options as possible. Under this specific condition, I might have just provided $data, however if you're wanting a reusable option you need to be more specific as to what data types you need as parameters and not all view models may have the same properties.

```
data-bind="colorAndTrans: { color: color, transValue: number }"
```

Hope this does more than answer your question!

Answer (score 2):

If you really get into complicated styling case, just accumulate all in the computed property. You can do it as Alex mentioned or a bit more readable:

```
vm.divStyle = ko.computed(function() {
        var styles = [];

        if (vm.isNested()) styles.push('nested');
        if (vm.isTabular()) styles.push('tabular');
        else styles.push('non-tabular');
        if (vm.color()) styles.push(vm.color());

        return styles.join(' ');
});
```

the main drawback is that you're moving a part of view definition into the viewmodel, that should be more independent. The alternative is to provide all the logic above as a plain js function call, and let knockout evaluate it.

Answer (score 2):

A couple more options:

Similar to the suggestions to use a computed, you can inline the expression:

```
<div data-bind="css: [color(), (number() < 10 ? 'translucent' : 'notTranslucent')].join(' ')">static dynamic css classes</div>
```

As an alternative to a custom binding handler that is specific to this case, you can make one that takes an array of mixed css specs and passes them to the original css handler:

```
<div data-bind="cssArray: [color, {translucent: number() < 10}]">static dynamic css classes</div>
```

The handler:

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.cssArray = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data, context) {
        var arr = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
      for (var i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) {
        var wrapped = function () { return ko.unwrap(arr[i]) };
        ko.bindingHandlers.css.update(element, wrapped, allBindingsAccessor, data, context);
      }
    }
  }
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tT9PK/39/)

Answer (score 1):

Nice question, the problem seems to be the binding `css` isn't thought to mix the two kinds, `color(): color() != ''` doesn't work (would be nice).

I like @Simon_waver's answer approach, simple and practical.

Maybe at the time of the question wasn't supported (Idk) but with current *knockout* also combining the classes works: `data-bind="css: computed"`

```
viewModel.computed = ko.pureComputed(function() {
   return viewModel.color() + (viewModel.number() < 10 ? ' translucent' : '');
});
```

Comment: I personally like this implementation of computed observables. This is certainly the best way to accomplish the functionality the asker is requesting without extending the knockout framework. However, I have found it much easier to maintain a code base built with knockout when the classes being toggled by the CSS binding are shown in object format. I work with a large team of people and we try to avoid using CSS bindings that hide the classnames inside the viewmodel. This development strategy makes it easy to see what is happening from the markup. That is why I choose to extend KO instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more elegant solution to this problem via computed property names (for [FF>34, Chrome, Safari>7.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility)):

```
<div data-bind="css: { [color]: true,'translucent': number() < 10 }">
    static dynamic css classes
</div>
```

Whereas `color` is a property with a string value.

If the value of `color` is an observable then we need to clear the classname before that observable updates. If we do not do this then each change will add another class and not remove the previous one. This can easily be accomplished manually but I wrote an extender for those who are interested.

```
ko.extenders.css = function(target, value) {
  var beforeChange;
  var onChange;

  //add sub-observables to our observable
  target.show = ko.observable(true);

  beforeChange = function(oldValue){
    target.show(false);
  }
  onChange = function(newValue){
    target.show(true);
  }
  target.subscribe(beforeChange, null, "beforeChange");
  target.subscribe(onChange);
  return target;
};
```

With this extender, your JavaScript code would look like this:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.color = ko.observable("red").extend({ css: true });
    this.number = ko.observable(9)
};
```

And your markup would be this simple:

```
<div data-bind="css: { [color()]: color.show(),'translucent': number() < 10 }">
    static dynamic css classes
</div>
```

I have a code pen demonstrating this technique:
http://codepen.io/USIUX/pen/WryGZQ

I have also submitted an issue with knockout in hopes that one day the custom extender will not be necessary: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/1990

Answer (score 0):

I'd create the `css` binding value in your viewmodel. You can define a `computed` that returns either an object or string.

Some examples, using ES2015:

```js
const App = function() {
  this.number = ko.observable(12);
  this.color = ko.observable("red");
  
  this.cssConfigObj = ko.pureComputed(() => ({
    "italic": this.number() > 10,
    [this.color()]: true
  }));
  
  this.cssConfigStr = ko.pureComputed(() => 
    `${this.color()} ${this.number() > 10 ? "italic" : ""}`
  );
};

ko.applyBindings(new App());
```

```css
.monospaced {
  font-family: monospace;
}

.italic {
  font-style: italic;
}

.red {
  color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div
  class="monospaced"
  data-bind="css: cssConfigObj"
>Hello world</div>

<div
  class="monospaced"
  data-bind="css: cssConfigStr"
>Hello world</div>
```