# CSS binding in Knockout to bind two classes where one is dynamic and the other static and evaluated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I think I've tried everything. It seems that binding dynamic classes like so:

```
<div data-bind="css: dynamicClass">
    Something
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {};

    viewModel.dynamicClass = ko.observable('blue');

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

doesn't work when I also try to bind a static evaluated class on the same element. Like so:

```
<div data-bind="css: { dynamicClass: true, staticClass: evaluator() === 5 }">
    Something
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {};

    viewModel.evaluator = ko.observable(5);
    viewModel.dynamicClass = ko.observable('blue');

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

And I've tried many different versions of this:

```
<div data-bind="css: { dynamicClass: (true == true), staticClass: evaluator() === 5 }">
```

---

```
<div data-bind="css: dynamicClass, css: { staticClass: evaluator() === 5 }">
```

---

```
<div data-bind="css: { dynamicClassComputed: (true == true), staticClass: evaluator() === 5 }">
    Something
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {};

    viewModel.evaluator = ko.observable(5);
    viewModel.dynamicClass = ko.observable('blue');
    viewModel.dynamicClassComputed = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return this.dynamicClass();
    }, viewModel);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

And in all cases the name of the property ("dynamicClass" or "dynamicClassComputed") is bound, not its value ("blue"). I do not want to use the `attr` binding since it replaces all classes on the element.

Is what I'm looking for possible in Knockout or not yet?

Comment: @Jeroen Yeah I guess I'm not that good at searching StackOverflow. It's not a solution but it's the only solution it seems :)

Comment: It's okay. Well written duplicates like your question are great for Stack Overflow: someone else may search for this issue with terms *you* used in your question, and easily find the duplicate one.

Comment: And some of us answer-writing junkies can write new answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256093/combine-dynamic-and-static-classes-through-css-binding-knockout-js/34416301#answer-34416301

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take a look into KnockoutJS internals, we'll see:

```
ko.bindingHandlers['css'] = {
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        if (value !== null && typeof value == "object") {
            ko.utils.objectForEach(value, function(className, shouldHaveClass) {
                shouldHaveClass = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(shouldHaveClass);
                ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, className, shouldHaveClass);
            });
        } else {
            value = ko.utils.stringTrim(String(value || '')); // Make sure we don't try to store or set a non-string value
            ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, element[classesWrittenByBindingKey], false);
            element[classesWrittenByBindingKey] = value;
            ko.utils.toggleDomNodeCssClass(element, value, true);
        }
    }
};
```

So, we have two orthogonal cases of 'css' binding usage:

1) We pass an object as 'css' binding parameter ('if (value !== null && typeof value == "object")'):

```
<div data-bind="css: { dynamicClass: true, staticClass: evaluator() === 5 }">
```

In this case 'dynamicClass' and 'staticClass' are treated as css style names and we'll get something like

```
<div class="dynamicClass staticClass">
```

in the resulting markup.

2) We pass an observable (that returns a string) as 'css' binding parameter:

```
<div data-bind="css: dynamicClass">
```

This means that 'dynamicClass' is something like:

```
dynamicClass = ko.observable("styleName1 styleName2")
```

and we'll get something like

```
<div class="styleName1 styleName2">
```

in the resulting markup.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I've been made aware that I can't do what I wanted but you made me understand why it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

`attr` and `css` must be combined. Try this :

```html
<div data-bind="attr: { 'class': dynamicClass }, css: { staticClass: evaluator() === 5 }">
    Something
</div>
```

If you have other static classes, and you don't want to erase it with the `attr` binding, just duplicate the binding handler css like that :

```html
<div data-bind="css2: dynamicClass, css: { staticClass: evaluator() === 5 }" class="test">
    Something
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     ko.bindingHandlers['css2'] = ko.bindingHandlers.css;
    
    var viewModel = {};

    viewModel.evaluator = ko.observable(5);
    viewModel.dynamicClass = ko.observable('blue');

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    
    
</script>
```