# Knockout HTML binding and length of HTML in terms of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have one string which is having html code. So I am binding in view like

```
<div data-bind="html : Notes()"></div>
```

Now I want add one class to div based on length of Notes with out Html elements.

Suppose `Notes = "<b>Hello</b>"` , then `Notes.length = 12 (With <b> and </b>)`

But I need to replace all html elements and I need to get length as 5(Hello).

How can I achieve this below line.

```
<div data-bind="html : Notes(), css:{myclass : Notes().length > 5}"></div>
```

Comment: instead of html use text

Comment: @guradio: If I use text, It will display with all elements as a string. Here problem is not with html binding. I need to check condition based on length of Notes() with out html elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a computed that creates a virtual element and returns its text length like so:

```
var noteLength = ko.computed(function() {
  var tempElement = document.createElement("div");
  tempElement.innerHTML = Notes();

  return tempElement.innerText.length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamic class by css property and then add static class by attr. property. Details are available in the below link. Do let me know if this does not help.

[combine dynamic and static classes through css binding, knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256093/combine-dynamic-and-static-classes-through-css-binding-knockout-js)