# add dynamic class with css binding

Tags: css, class, magento, knockout.js, data-binding

I want to add a class behind `payment-method` by function with the knockout css binding (in Magento 2.1).
So this is the current code:

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
```

The class is returned by `getCode()` which works above with the id and value.
So I thought I could do just:

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked()), getCode()}">
```

But then it fails with:

> knockout.js:2624 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unable to parse bindings.
>   Bindings value: css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked()), getCode() }
>   Message: Unexpected token }

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: getCode()">
```

This works.

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {getCode()}">
```

This doesn't.

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}, attr: {'class': getCode()}">
```

This works too but will overwrite the `payment-method` class and the `_active` class isn't set either initally anymore.

How do I set that dynamic class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @tyler_mitchell helped me find the solution myself through this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21528681/928666

I can do:

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="attr: { 'class': 'payment-method ' + getCode() }, css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
```

Not brilliant but well...

Comment: But if you can add a function easily I'd do what tyler_mitchell proposed.

Answer (score 3):

This piece of code is redundant, as the css data-bind is getting overwrite with your attr binding.

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}, attr: {'class': getCode()}">
```

This is how you can do your dynamic class (assumption these properties are observable):

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: CSS">

self.CSS = ko.computed(function() {
    var code = self.getCode();
    var isChecked = self.isChecked();
    return code + ' ' + (code == isChecked ? '_active' : '');
}, viewModel);
```

Comment: Thanks, but assuming I can not add another function. According to the documentation I can set multiple css classes. Does that not work with function arguments?

Comment: No you can `<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked()), getCode() }">` -> http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html, but this may not work as its a mix of dynamic class and setting static, so would be better practice to do it in one place. I would just say this is a more optimal way of doing it. As its only one call instead of several

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it gives an error, I updated my question with the exact error message.

Comment: To me that error means you can't mix static and dynamic. Do one or other. If you update question with what getcode and ischecked. I could give you exact solution or jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Another example should anyone need it

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'class': 'mainClass' + (dynamicClassSetOnce ? ' ' + dynamicClassSetOnce : '' }, css: { 'mainClass--focussed': isFocussed }">
...
</div>
```