# KnockoutJS add static and dynamic class name using css property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to add a dynamic classname which will come from javascript based on some check. But one class `navigate-forward` is there which is also displayed based on some check. How to combine both?

Following is my code -

```
<span class="menu-item" data-bind="text: data.description,
            css: {
                    'navigate-forward': !child.action,
                    child.className //I tried something like this which doesn't work
            }"></span>
```

`child.className` will have a value based on some check in javascript code. And whatever value it gives I want to add that class to this `span`.

Ex. if `child.className` is `tooltip` then that class should be added to the span.

**output**

```
<span class="menu-item navigate-forward tooltip">Menu item</span>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [combine dynamic and static classes through css binding, knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256093/combine-dynamic-and-static-classes-through-css-binding-knockout-js)

Answer (score 0):

The `css:` binding only accepts a list of classes and whether to apply them or not. You could use:

`<div data-bind="attr: { 'class': MyPropertyName }" class="initialClass"></div>`

But this would overwrite any pre-existing classes (`initialClass`) on the element.

Take a look at https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class where there is a custom binding handler that allows you to specify a dynamic class:

```
<div class="initialClass" data-bind="class: MyPropertyName"></div>
```

This solution will combine the existing class attribute with the `MyPropertyName` property.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function vm(){
  var self = this;
  self.className = ko.observable("class2");
}


(function(){
var viewModel = new vm();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<label class="class1" data-bind="css:className">Your Element</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the style and css bindings with an object that holds all your styles and classes instead of using individual class names. This allows for a more programmatic approach.

```js
function viewModel(){
  var self = this;
  this.description = ko.observable('placeholder text');
  this.useBlue = ko.observable(false);
  this.borderClass = ko.observable("red-border");

  this.classes = ko.pureComputed(function(){
    var obj = {
      'blue-background': self.useBlue()
    };
    obj[self.borderClass()] = true;
    return obj;
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
.blue-background {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.red-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<span class="menu-item" data-bind="text: description, css: classes"></span>
<br/>
            
<input type="button" data-bind="click: function(){ useBlue(!useBlue()) }" value="toggle" />
```